# Extract values with ampersands from query string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to extract the baz value from the following query string:

```
foo=bar&baz=qux&norf&corge=grault
```

The problem is that the value of baz contains a &. I've had some success using a lookhead like this:

```
/baz=(.*)(?=[^=]*&)/
```

However, it can't handle end of line or when there are more than one key-value after it.

Is there a regexp that can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
baz=([^=]*)(?=&|$)
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/1

Answer (score 1):

Use following `regex`:

```
baz=(\w+&\w+)
```

**Explanation**

1. `baz=`: matches the characters baz= literally (case sensitive)
2. `(\w+&\w+)`: Capturing Group
   \w+ match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
3. `&`: matches the characters `&` literally

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jC7kN1/1)

```js
var queryString = 'foo=bar&baz=qux&norf&corge=grault';

var value = queryString.match(/baz=(\w+&\w+)/)[1];

document.write(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\bbaz=([^=&]+(?:&[^=&\n]+)?)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS4zH4/5)

In case you have multiple `&`-containing values, you can use

```
\bbaz=([^=&]+(?:&[^=&\n]+)*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS4zH4/6)

Comment: Hi. It doesn't include the ampersand. It should extract "qux&norf".

Comment: Now it will. Perhaps, `\n` is redundant, but in a demo, or if you have input with linebreaks, it should be present.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You updated the answer. Thanks. Is it possible to make it so that it's optional? That it might contain an ampersand but can also be without.

Comment: Yes, I have made the second `&...` optional with `(?:...)?`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS4zH4/5) If you have even more &s in the same ke-value, replace `?` with `*`: `\bbaz=([^=&]+(?:&[^=&\n]+)*)`.